# Caching Images in Memory in more that one server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, memcached

First I have to mention some basics of caching. If you want to cache an object in a memory out of the heap thTe object should be serializable because it has to be transfer over the network. Therefore if you want to cache an Image Magic object you have to convert it to memory stream and then when you are reading it you have again convert a memory stream into an Image magic object.

However if you want to use MemoryCache which uses the heap memory you can cache every object without serializable.

Now my situation: I have two AWS server that host 16 of our websites with a load balancer. So we have 16 instances of the same application in two different website. I have more than 2000 pictures which are on S3. Currently I am reading them and as memory stream and then convert them into the Image magic and combine it with user pictures and show the end user a combined image. To improve the performance I have to cache the image magic images and read them from cache which remove the time of conversion of memory stream to image magic but if I use Memorycache there would be 16 isolated application pools so very soon the memory will be full and it would not be effective because the load balancer will distribute the request between the two servers. so if the first request goes to the server one and x is cached there then the second request goes to the server two then again the x is cached in the server two. And if I use the memcache then the serializing is the problem.

Aditional info: the web application is in MVC.

Comment: Which region are you in ? Have you looked at EFS from AWS http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/whatisefs.html ?

Comment: Look at [this](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/performance/caching/distributed.html) page for some inspiration.

Comment: How often do the 2k images change why would not have them local to the boxes ?

Comment: I read the EFS. It is a storage system not a caching one. I need a cache system that is shared between the servers. Memcache seems a solution here but I need to serialize the object which is very time consuming.

Comment: Jerorn Heier. Thanks.  It seems that I have to avoid the in-memory cache over multiple servers as Microsoft explicitly mentions [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/performance/caching/distributed.html): "Redis Cache is a caching solution which gives you high throughput and low latency as compared to SQL Cache. Also, you should avoid using the in-memory implementation (MemoryCache) in multi-server environments."

Answer (score 0):

I did lots of researches. There is no way to cache objects  that are in heap and cache them over network without serializing them. Any object that is transferring over network has to be serializable. So there is no solution for this question that how we can put an image into a cache which not in heap. Actually you can serialize an image and cache it, but there would be no point to do that because it requires serializing and deserializing which have lots of overload on the server.